# Does the phrase "Someone is experiencing something" have a negative meaning?

Tags: meaning

Does the phrase "Someone is experiencing something" have a negative meaning?

There are lots of examples that show negative connotations:

> We're experiencing a problem please try again.
>
> We are currently experiencing temporary issues with our service.
>
> Currently Experiencing Phone Outages
>
> Five countries currently experiencing disputed elections.

Are there any positive connotations (also need some examples)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the construction

> [Someone] is experiencing [something]

can have positive connotations.

All you have to do is supply positive objects in the pattern:

> Alaska is experiencing unusually pleasant weather right now.
>
> The bicycle club is experiencing a boom in membership applications.
>
> We are experiencing excellent returns on our investments.